# Increasing Selling Spaces

Tags: firefall

In Firefall you get eight slots to sell items in on the global market. Is there any way to increase this limit? Can VIP increase this limit? What is the cost to increase the limit if you can?

Comment: I don't know if they've changed it from when I last used VIP time (so I could get the +2 manufacturing slots before they changed the whole manufacturing system) ... but it did also give me additional sales slots ... I want to say it was either +4 or +8 slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the free VIP status that they gave as a reward for the chosen invasion, I've been able to confirm that VIP gives you +8 (to a total of 16) slots for market transactions.

I'm not aware of any other way to raise the limit.

Comment: Does it unlock the limit perm or just until VIP runs out?

Comment: @YoungGuilo : I can't confirm that it hasn't changed since last time (as my VIP hasn't run out yet), but the last time it reverted back once VIP ended ... of course, it doesn't remove things from the list, so you have to wait for things to sell or delete thing to get back under 8 to put more things up for sale.  (back when there were things that took 5+ days to research, I bought the 1 day VIP, did a day of manufacturing things, then loaded up 4 5-day research items just as it was near expiring)